# Ruby: index wont return the result for second parameter if same parameter passed twice with second parameter value blank

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following index method in controller

```
def index
  if params.key?(:item)
    @items = Item.get_items.where(item: params[:item])
  else
    @items = Item.get_items
end
```

Model:

```
Class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item_resources, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :resources, through: :item_resources

  def self.get_items
    includes(item_resources: {resource: :item_groups})
      .order('item_resources.area ASC')
  end
end
```

Views:

index.json.jbuilder

```
json.array! @items, partial: ‘items/item’, as: :item
_item.json.jbuilder
```

_item.json.jbuilder

```
json.something1 item.something1
json.item_layout do
  json.template_key item.layout
  json.merge! item.layout_config if item.layout_config.present?
end
json.something (item.item_details) do |item_detail|
  json.partial! ‘item_details/item_detail’, item_detail: item_detail
end
```

I am using postman for testing as follows

```
http://localhost:3000/items?item=some_item
http://localhost:3000/items?item=some_item&item=other_item
```

The above works fine

```
http://localhost:3000/items?item=some_item&item=
```

When i try to pass item twice with second parameter value blank it wont return the result for second parameter but returns result for first parameter.

It generates sql with `IN ('some_item', '')`

Comment: Look at your SQL--you're trying to pass in an array when a single value is expected, no? (Honestly I don't remember, but there's a difference between using an array of values and a single value.)

Comment: No @DaveNewton, that's correct. If you give to where an array an `in` SQL is used

Comment: Yes its generating SQL with `Item IN ('some_item', '')` but it doesnt return the record with `item = '' ` :(